# How to make app compile fail if string resource is not found in strings file?

Tags: android, xml, mdm, lint

I have an `ImageView` in my layout file. I have contentDescription defined for that view with `someString`. I don't have `someString` defined in my `strings.xml`  When I use `@+` for string resource in `contentDescription`, I get warning in Android studio saying Cannot resolve symbol resource identifier `"@+string/someString"`

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_above ="@+id/attachmentName"
        android:contentDescription="@+strings/someString">
```

Update : I know it can be solved by using `android:contentDescription="@strings/someString` but I want to scan my app to see if there are any similar issues in my existing code.

This seems like a silly bug but I wonder why Android Studio still lets me compile my app. This issue is causing crash when used used by app monitored by certain MDM.

I am wondering how can I avoid these issues in my app. Can I make a lint check which will stop compiling my app when this case is encounter.

Comment: Use `contentDescription="strings/someString"` to access string which have `someString` name in strings.xml

Comment: You mean "@strings/someString"? I know it can be solved by removing + but I want to avoid similar bugs in future and wondering if I could set something in lint to not compile my app it encounters this issue.